# How to filter results in tagfunc?

Tags: tags

I'm using Vim to edit Erlang source files. As function names in Erlang are only unique within a module (unlike in C), the tags support "out of the box" is not perfect (for example there are more than 200 function clauses called `encode` in the dependencies of my project and in the standard library). I tried to create a `tagfunc` that will filter the results by module name:

```
function! ErlangTag(pattern, flags, info)
  let l:funcname = expand("<cword>")
  let l:line = getline(".")
  let l:match_res = matchlist(line, "[a-zA-Z0-9'_]*:" . l:funcname)
  if len(l:match_res) > 0
    let [l:mod, l:fun] = split(l:match_res[0], ":")
    return filter(taglist(a:pattern), 'v:val.module ==' . l:mod)
  else
    return taglist(a:pattern)
  endif
endfunction
```

but when I type `g-]` on the `jsx:encode` call (when the cursor is over `encode`), I get this error message:

```
Error detected while processing function ErlangTag:
line    6:
E121: Undefined variable: jsx
Error detected while processing function ErlangTag:
line    6:
E15: Invalid expression: v:val.module ==jsx
```

How do I pass the module name to the filter expression? I also tried this line:

```
    return filter(taglist(a:pattern), 'v:val.module == l:mod')
```

but got a different error:

```
Error detected while processing function ErlangTag:
line    6:
E716: Key not present in Dictionary: module == l:mod
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"module" is optionally present in tags.  The correct form of the filter is:

```
return filter(taglist(a:pattern), 'get(v:val, "module", "") ==# l:mod')
```

Using `get()` to compensate for the possibly missing field and using `==#` meaning case sensitive string equality.

Comment: One example where dealing with lambdas instead of strings might be easier